# slick slider add gap only between adjacent slides

Tags: javascript, css, slider, carousel, slick.js

I am creating a carousel using the npm package "slick-carousel", as per working code below.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>Responsive Slick Carousel</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css">
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="carousel">
                <div style="background-color: blue;">Slide 1</div>
                <div style="background-color: red;">Slide 2</div>
                <div style="background-color: green;">Slide 3</div>
                <div style="background-color: orange;">Slide 4</div>
            </div>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('.carousel').slick({
                        dots: true,
                        infinite: true,
                        slidesToShow: 3,
                        slidesToScroll: 1,
                        responsive: [
                            {
                                breakpoint: 1024,
                                settings: {
                                    slidesToShow: 2,
                                    slidesToScroll: 1,
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                breakpoint: 600,
                                settings: {
                                    slidesToShow: 1,
                                    slidesToScroll: 1,
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    });
                });

            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Now, I want to show a gap between the slides, only where the slides are beside each other and not on the sides.

So if Slide 1, Slide 2, and Slide 3 are showing, there should be a gap only shown between Slide 1 and Slide 2, as well as Slide 2 and Slide 3. There should be no gap before Slide 1, and no gap after Slide 3.

[image]

Is this possible to accomplish?

Thank you,